# Writing a trim method

Tags: java

I'm writing a method to trim certain characters from a string. s1 is the actual string, and s2 is the char that you want to trim from the string. In my main method, I called:

```
    String text = U.trim("what ?? the hell", '?');
```

And the rest of the code is the trim method I wrote. The problem is that whenever I put two ? marks together it only trims one of them, but if I put them apart it trims them fine. I don't know what I did wrong, and I even put print statements in the code itself to try to debug it, and if you run the code you'll see that the two question marks are at c[5] and c[6], and below the if statement if that char is a ? mark it'll replace it and print out "5;?", but I don't know why when it's comparing c[6], and the question mark it returns as false, since c[6] is a question mark. Please help.

```
    static String trim(String s1, char s2) {
    char c[] = new char[s1.length()];
    String text = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        c[i] = s1.charAt(i);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println("C" + i + ": " + c[i]);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Start: " + i);
        if (c[i] == s2) {
            System.out.println(i + ";" + s2);

            for (int j = i; j < s1.length(); j++) {

                if (j != s1.length() - 1) {
                    c[j] = c[j + 1];
                } else {
                    c[j] = '\0';
                }

            }

        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        text = text + c[i];

    }

    return text;
}
```

I try the pattern class, it didn't trim the question marks.

```
    String text = "Hello ????";
    text.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("?"), "");
    System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Iterate through the string backwards.

Comment: Or just use `s1.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("?"), "")`. I'm not sure if that's what you're trying to do, it's pretty hard to tell what you intend without an explicit statement of what you expect.

Comment: Or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,%20int) with appropriate args.

Comment: It also has a `toCharArray()` method.

Comment: Cannot find the pattern method.

Comment: `java.util.regex.Pattern`. It is a class.

Comment: I tried the pattern class method. It didn't trim the question marks. Codes above.

Comment: Strings are immutable, you need to assign the return value of `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use s1.replace("?", "")
This is similar to replaceAll, but replaceAll uses a regex.

replace() replaces all occurances in the string.

Now, as to what you did wrong:

When you found a match in the character array, you shift the remaining characters towards the head.

Starting with "abc??def", your first match is at i=3.
You shift all the remaining characters to get "abc?def"
Then, you increment i to 4, and carry on.
c[4] is 'd' at this point.

So, the error is that when you shifted the characters to the left, you still increment i anyway, causing the first shifted character to be skipped.

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH. So just put i-- in the else statement. FIXED IT. You're a genius. Thank you so much. I was going to drive myself crazy finding the bug.